# Jquery .click event handler not working for class selector in CHROME

Tags: jquery, html, css, eventhandler

When I try to set the same opacity as mouseover when a .click event occurs, it doesn't work.

What I've tried:
-different selectors (li, menu:li, li:a, .li-navclass, nav-text)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```css
.container {
 position: absolute;
 background:url('../images/bgpic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
 height: 655px;
 width: 900px;
}

.titlehdr {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px; 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 897px;
 height: 110px;
}

.title-div {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90px;

 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}


.title {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;

 font-size: 70px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Mesquite Std;
 letter-spacing: 1.2px;

}

.barandgrill-div {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: bottom;

}

.barandgrill-text {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;

}

/*---------------Nav Menu----------------*/
.menu {
 padding-left: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-container {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 top: 100px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 900px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #901423;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #111111;
}

.menu {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
   overflow: hidden;
    font-color: #000000;
}

.li-navclass {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}


li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 1em;
 font-size: 150%;
}


.nav-text {
    color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: bold;
   opacity: .3;
}


.nav-container ul a {
 text-decoration: none;
    word-spacing: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: Segoe Script;
}

/*---------------Content----------------*/

.content {
 display: block;
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: #111111;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

/*---------------Footer------------------*/

.foot {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.ftr-button {
 position: relative;
 top: -5px;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgb(147, 104, 55);
}


.ftr-links {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
}


.vert-line {
 height: 13px;
 border-right: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Sticky Navigation Tutorial</title>                  
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="css/screen.css"/>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container"> 
  
  <div class="wrapper"> 


  <!--Title-->
     <div class="titlehdr">
      <div class="title-div">
       <p class="title">Donatelo's</p>
      </div>

      <div class="barandgrill-div">
       <p class="barandgrill-text">Mediterranean Bar and Grill</p>
      </div>
     </div>

  <!--Navigation Menu-->
     <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="menu">
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="index.html" class="nav-text">Story</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="menu.html" class="nav-text">Menu</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="gallery.html" class="nav-text">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="catering.html" class="nav-text">Catering</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-text">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>  
     </div>

  <!--Grey Box-->
     <div class="content">
      <div id="sidebar">
       <div id="scroller">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

  <!--footer-->
     <div class="foot">
      <ul class="ftr-links">
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="index.html" class="ftr-button">Story</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="menu.html" class="ftr-button">Menu</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="gallery.html" class="ftr-button">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="catering.html" class="ftr-button">Catering</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="contact.html" class="ftr-button">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">Copyright © 2015 Agabi Mediterranean Restaurant</p>  
     </div> 
  </div>


</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav-text").mouseover(function() {
  $( this ).css( "opacity", ".8" );
});

$(".nav-text").mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css( "opacity", ".2");
});

$(".ftr-button").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "rgb(132, 131, 129)");
});
$(".ftr-button").mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "rgb(147, 104, 55)");
});

$(".nav-text").click(function() {
 $(this).css("opacity", ".8");
});
});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your .nav-text is inside an a tag. So you click the link and a new page is opened. You need to preventDefault the a tag if you dont want to open a new page after click.

Do something like this - note, your link will not work anymore:

```
$(".nav-text").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("opacity", ".8");
});
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, take a look at the :focus in csshttp://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: I just want to make it so that when i click, the text i click on remains highlighted.